"field" vs. "vector field"
Is the "field" in the "vector field" as the same "field" in algebra: as the commutative ring with the multiplicative inverse?

If yes, then the "vector field" must have a relation to the vector space where the coefficient of the vector is a "field" in algebra?

If no, please explain and please give some counter example. (Like coefficient of vector is not a field but only a ring, forming a Module?)



I really don't think the usage of field in "vector field" has anything to do with the ring-theoretic object. A vector field is just a vector-valued function; I think the field here is more of a physics-type meaning, like "gravity field" or "magnetic field".

No, a vector field is basically just a vector-valued map, i.e. a map whose codomain is a vector space (typically its domain is a topological space or a manifold). [Actually it's more correct to say it is a section of a vector bundle].

There's too many math concepts and not enough words. So, unfortunately, you get strange clashes of terminology in mathematics, such as "Let $V$ be a vector field over the field $\mathbb Q$". Just don't read too much into it.

No, the field in vector field comes from physics — electric field, gravitational field, magnetic field ….
The word field in English has these two different mathematical meanings. In other languages, the terms are different. For example, in French the algebraic field is corps (body) and the vector field is champ (field, like of wheat). In German, we have, analogously, Körper and Feld.
